# Iam Passing an value when iam redirecting the template in django

Tags: python, django, templates, redirect

I created Login Page and I submitted that page it goes to another page I want that particular username on another page so I am passing that name when I am redirecting the page but it doesn't work for me...

```
urls.py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from .import views

urlpatterns = [
         path('dash/',views.Dash,name='Dash'),
]


Dash.html
<div class="flex-grow-1">
<span class="fw-semibold d-block">{{name}}</span>
</div>


views.py
def Login(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
     username=request.POST['username']
     password=request.POST['password']
     user=auth.authenticate(username=username,password=password)
     if user is not None:
         request.session['user'] = username
         auth.login(request,user)
         return redirect('/dash',{name:user})

This is my code why I am not getting the name? Please anyone help me
```

Comment: (1) You aren't showing the code for the `Dash` view. (2) You don't need to store `user` separately in the session since you're using `auth.login` anyway. (3) `redirect` doesn't have a signature like that (and in any case, that's not quite valid Python syntax for what you want.) (4) Please look at Django's form views (there's a premade view for logging in and redirecting!) instead of working with `request.POST` by hand.

Comment: You don't have to create new session variables, if the login is successful, then you can use ```{{ request.username }}``` in template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If login is successful. You don't need to pass the username in the template. You can access the user in template as **{{request.user}}** and username as **{{request.user.username}}**.